# Dual screen Airplay, balck screen after reload AVPlayer

Tags: xcode, swift

I try do scroll view with multiple video. I have blank screen in this case:

1. I create Scroll View
2. Add `AVFoundation` -> `AVPlayer` each slide.
3. Each AVPlayer keep in array

Everything works almost ok, in one case is black screen. When I connect via Airplay to the TV and move scroll view. On my videos is shows black screen. Voice is still available. Below is my function to show video on Dual Screen. Any idea what is wrong? When I checking on simulator works ok.

In debugger problem is here: "let avPlayerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: o.o)"

```
func loadContentSecondScreen() {

    var iPage:Int = self.isPage

    if (iPage == 0) {
        iPage = 1
    }//end if

    let oAllScreens = UIScreen.screens()

    // Jesli sa podpiete ekrany.
    if (oAllScreens.count > 1 && self.oSecondScreen != nil) {
        // Usuwamy stare widoki.
        if (self.oSecondWindow != nil) {
            for view in self.oSecondWindow!.subviews {
                view.removeFromSuperview()
            }//end for
        }//end if

        // Czarne tlo.
        let view:UIView = UIView(frame: self.oSecondScreen!.bounds)
            view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()

        self.oSecondWindow?.hidden = false
        self.oSecondWindow?.addSubview(view)

        // Jesli sa elementy do wyswietlania.
        if (self.Slides > 0) {

            let obj:GalleryAsset = self.Content[iPage-1]
            let file:String      = obj.zoom

            let ImageContent:UIView = UIView(frame: self.oSecondScreen!.bounds)

            if (obj.type == "jpg" || obj.type == "jpeg" || obj.type == "png") {
                // Ladujemy obrazy do slidera.
                // Czy plik istenieje i mozna go zaladowac.
                if (self.fileExistsInAssetFolder(obj.zoom) == true) {
                    let imageImage: UIImage   = UIImage(contentsOfFile: self.pathAsset.stringByAppendingPathComponent(obj.zoom))!
                    let imageView:UIImageView = UIImageView(image: imageImage)
                        imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
                        imageView.frame       = self.oSecondScreen!.bounds
                        ImageContent.addSubview(imageView as UIView)
                }

            } else if (obj.type == "mp4") {

                // Ladujemy video do slidera.
                if (self.fileExistsInAssetFolder(obj.zoom) == true) {

                    let VideoContainer:UIView = UIView(frame: self.oSecondScreen!.bounds)
                        VideoContainer.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor

                    for o in self.avPlayerList {
                        if (iPage-1 == o.i) {
                            //if !o.o {
                                let avPlayerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: o.o)
                                    avPlayerLayer.frame = VideoContainer.bounds
                                VideoContainer.layer.addSublayer(avPlayerLayer)
                                ImageContent.addSubview(VideoContainer)
                            //}//end if let
                        }//end if
                    }//end for
                }//end if

            }//end if

             self.oSecondWindow?.addSubview(ImageContent)
        }
    }

}//end loadContentSecondScreen()
```